# Looping through JSON in node and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, express

I am trying display the results from the twitter api in a new line for each tweet. I get it looking ok in console.log but not when displaying it in express. Currently in express I am using a paragraph tag.`<p><%=tweets%></p>` What do I need to do to get my array values to show up each on new lines.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var output = [];
  twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline',{user_id:xxxxxxx, screen_name:'xxxxxxxxx'}, function(error, params, response){
      if(error) throw error;

      for(var text in params){
          output.push(params[text].text); //comes in a huge string no '/n' allowed
      }

      res.render('index', { 
        title: 'Home Page', //renders fine
        tweets: output //renders as a large string I try output.join("\n") does not render
      });
  });
```

Comment: Does your `title` render ok in your template? Can you improve your question, showing what `console.log` outputs and how your template looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML, newlines are generally disregarded. If you use a tag like `<pre>` though instead of `<p>` and use `tweets: output.join('\n')`, you should see newlines as you expect since `<pre>` will display content as-is.